# Set builder for $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\dots,\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I write the set builder for a set
$$\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\dots,\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}\}?$$

Comment: You have accepted an answer. That said, I hope you want this only for practice in set builder notation. If you actually want to write this for someone to understand, do it as you did in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways:
$$\{\{1,\dots,k\} \mid k\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$$

$$\left\{S\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\} \Bigg| S\not=\emptyset \land\bigwedge_{i\in S} (i\in S\setminus\{1\} \implies i-1\in S)\right\}$$